# Angular Reactive Form not showing expected value

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am using the `FormBuilder` module to create a strictly typed reactive form, but I am only able to get values to display correctly when I don't need to specify whether or not the control is disabled. For example, if I have the following:

TS:

```
testForm = this.fb.group({
    testControl: '123',
});
```

HTML:
`<input formControlName="testControl" type="text">`

Then the input displays the value `123` as expected and I can successfully update the value with `setValue`. However, if I change the typescript code to:

```
testForm = this.fb.group({
    testControl: [{ value: '123', disabled: true}],
});
```

Then it defaults to the correct value, but if I ever need to change it with `setValue` or `patchValue`, it begins displaying as `[object Object]`.

Is `testControl: [{ value: '123', disabled: true}]` not the correct way to initialize a control that can be disabled? Is  `this.testForm.get('testControl').setValue({ value: 'abcdefg', disabled: false })` not the correct way to update the value? What am I doing wrong?

I've also tried `this.testForm.get('testControl').setValue('abcdefg')` when updating the value, but my IDE complains that a string isn't assignable to parameter of type `{ value: string; disabled: boolean; }`.

You can mess around with a similar example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ntcvra?file=src/app/profile-editor/profile-editor.component.ts

You'll just have to click the "Profile Editor" button, then click "Update Profile" at the bottom and you'll see the city input change to [object Object].

Comment: Would you please share your code in codepen.io or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `control.disable()` or `control.enable()`, where `control` is your `this.testForm.get('testControl')`

Answer (score 1):

use the disable() or enable() method.

```
    testForm = this.fb.group({
        testControl: ['123', {disabled: true}],
    });

    this.profileForm.get('address.city')?.setValue('abcdefg');
    this.profileForm.get('address.city')?.disable()
```

Answer (score 0):

check this!

get address() {return this.profileForm.get('address') as FormGroup;}

updateProfile() {this.address.controls?.['city']?.setValue('123');}